# How do I set the URL for a new page/view when using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting to use/wrap my head around MVC, but I'm still a little confused about where the actual URL for each view is defined.  So far, I have 2 controllers and 2 views.  The first controller works, and creates the correct view under the URL http://localhost:60480/Example, but I'm not even sure where it actually defines the view to be displayed on Example page.  How would I define the URL for the second page/view, so that a hyperlink on "Example" could load the second view with the second controller?

Basically, I want to create a hyperlink on /Example that will take me to /Example2 or some other page.  Any suggestions/help towards MVC would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, and I'm aware that my terminology may be a bit off, so don't be afraid to correct me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a file called `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start`.  This defines the relationship between the url and the controller/action.

If no-one has changed this, it will look like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

http://localhost/Example will match the default route, setting the controller to ExampleController.  As there's no action on the URI, it will be set to the default action "Index".

So this will hit the method 'Index' on controller ExampleController.cs

To get to your second controller, simply put the controller name (minus 'controller') in the url:  http://localhost/Example2  will call the Index method.   To get a different method/action: http://localhost/Example2/ActionMethodOnController2

```
public class Example2Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionMethodOnController2()
    {
        ...
        return View();
```

which will then give you the view with the same name as the action/method.  It's possible to have views named differently, but not recommended.

In the default route, it will be returning the view based on Index.cshtml

> I want to create a hyperlink

You can use `HtmlHelpers` to build links for you, eg:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Caption", ActionName, ControllerName)
@Html.ActionLink("Link Caption", "ActionMethodOnController2", "Example2")
```

Comment: If I have a folder for my views (Views->Examples->Example.cshtml, Example2.cshtml), would that affect the controller being able to find that view?  I tried going to /Example2, but it's saying "The view 'Index' or its master was not found", yet  I clearly have an Index method that returns a blank view.

Comment: Your question mentioned 2 controllers, so for this your views would be Views/Example1/Index.cshtml and Views/Example2/Index.cshtml.  For the views in your comment, add a method to your `ExamplesController` with the same name as the view (minus .cshtml) and use the code I provided for ActionMethodOnController2 (ie copy this + rename).  Your url is http://localhost/[controller]/[action]  - so for the two views in your comment, this would need to be http://localhost/Examples/Index (index is optional so works with just http://localhost/Examples) and http://localhost/Examples/Example2

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!  What's the point of ever making more than one controller if you can just make a new method for each view?

Comment: Couple of reasons.  The controller name is part of the URL, so becomes symantic (has meaning).  Eg //local/Dogs/List vs //local/Cats/List, rather than //local/home/dogslist. or //local/Dogs/View/3 rather than //local/home/viewdogs?id=3. This can also be used for SEO (search engine optimisation).  It also has an effect when you come to write unit-tests.  But mostly separation-of-concerns - the DogsController only has to deal with dogs and knows nothing about cats.